# Unable to open /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:01.0/resource

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, pci

I am trying to open an absolute path of a PCI device in C code

```
 fd = open("/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:01.0/resource", O_RDWR);

 if (fd < 0) {
            printf("Not found %s\n", path);
            return -1;
    }
```

But it gives me an error saying Not found /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:01.0/resource

Can anyone please point me out what I am doing here?

Comment: Well, does that path exist on your system?  What device do you think it is?

Comment: Yes , I checked it and it is there on my system.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `ls -l /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:01.0/resource` ?  Also, use `perror` instead of `printf` to print the errno text as well, because it will give you a more detailed reason for the failure.

Comment: -r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan  1 00:03 /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:01.0/resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to open the path for read/write, but it is only readable (that's what the `-r--r--r--` in `ls -l` output means).  You'll need to change `O_RDWR` to `O_RDONLY`.

Comment: Ah, I see but can I make it chmod 777  /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:01.0/resource?

Comment: You're welcome to try.  I have no idea what the device is, or how this will work.